# Can't access a Google Drive project folder in Visual Studio Code

Tags: files

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 (just installed).
I've setup my Google account so I'm able to access my Google Drive folder within the Files app.

However, when I use Visual Studio Code and click the Open Folder button, the Files window that opens does not like my Google Drive folder as an option to choose.

I'd appreciate suggestions for fixing this.

Thanks.

Comment: What you see in Files is just a list of the Driver contents, not the actual files or folders. You may download from there and save elsewhere but not use it directly as if they were normal folders or files. Files is NOT a Google Drive sync client, there are no official sync clients for Linux. There are a few unofficial ones, some free, some commercial.